# error with SQL foreign key stating parent key not there but i have checked that it is

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I get an error when adding a foreign key to this table:

> Error at line 2/16: ORA-02298: cannot validate (.FK_PATIENT_APPOINTMENT) - parent keys not found

This is the SQL I'm using:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Patient
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_patient_appointment
        FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_ID)
        REFERENCES Appointment(Appointment_ID);
```

The tables are created using:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Appointment 
(
    Appointment_ID INT,
    AppointmentDate DATE,
    AppointmentTime TIMESTAMP,
    AppointmentLocation VARCHAR2(255),
    Nurse_ID INT,
    Intervention_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Appointment_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Patient 
(
    Patient_ID INT,
    PatientFirstName VARCHAR2(50),
    PatientLastName VARCHAR2(50),
    PatientDOB DATE,
    PatientContact VARCHAR2(20),
    PatientAddress VARCHAR2(255),
    PatientGP VARCHAR2(50),
    PatientAlert VARCHAR2(255),
    Appointment_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Patient_ID)
);
```

I dropped the `Patient` table to make sure that it was exactly as it was with this code here.

The following are the foreign keys I am trying to add; it is only the ones with the `Patient` that don't work somehow. I can't add the foreign key in manually either at the saved created tables.

```sql
-- This causes the error
ALTER TABLE PATIENT 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_id
        FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_ID)
        REFERENCES Appointment (Appointment_ID);
```

Greatly appreciate any help thank you

I know that this is basic SQL coding but I just need to pass my assignment and show SQL that works and so I can query the tables !

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't find the answers anywhere else

Comment: As I'm not familiar with oracle-apex: Is the database your using an Oracle-DB or can another DBMS be used? 
Is there already data in any table when you try to add the constraints?

Comment: Your code runs without errors [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4DfF29E_)

Comment: Are you sure that you only want each patient to be able to make a single appointment? Would it not be better to remove the `appointment_id` column from the `patient` table and have a `patient_id` column in the `appointment` table and have the foreign key going from `appointment` to `patient` rather than the way you have done it from `patient` to `appointment`?

Comment: Hey @MT0 thank you kindly for these suggestions, been mad busy trying to get assignments done. You have both made great suggestions and it makes a lot more sense to be honest. Will try these soon but I think it is a much better design, thank you so much, you've dug me out of a hole a lot :D

Comment: @a.copter, I will try this and let you know, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4DfF29E_)

---

You appear to have put data into your table **before** creating the constraints.

Either:

1. Empty the table:

   ```sql
   TRUNCATE TABLE patient;
   ```
2. Delete the rows with no matching values in the `appointment` table.

   ```sql
   DELETE FROM patient p
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM   appointment a
                     WHERE  a.Appointment_ID = p.Appointment_ID);
   ```
3. Or insert appointments into the `appointment` table for all the patients that are missing appointments.

And then your constraint will can be created and you can try to `INSERT` the data back into the table (provided the constraints validate).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DHVNJX1J)